# correct way of shelve changes in TFS as a daily backup

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I work in many ASP.NET projects at once in VS 2019; I use TFS (without git), with a local workspace. As a way to make sure I have a "shelveset as a backup" in case I could lose my local work (hd fault, robbery, sticky fingers, lazy mind...), I am thinking of following these steps:

At the end of the day, I create a shelveset named with my username, preserving local changes.

The next morning, I continue working ignoring my first shelveset; Again, at the end of the day, I create a SECOND shelveset with my username+"2". When I'm sure it has been created without errors, I proceed to delete the first shelveset.

And the next morning I do the same, and so on...

What do you think guys, is it a good approach to make sure I will not lose any local changes in case of disaster?

Comment: Why not just backup your mapped workspace, from wherever it lives (probably something like `%userprofile\appdata\roaming\microsoft\visual studio...`) to a remote location (OneDrive for example)?

Comment: Because that would take too much time and space (15 gb); I only need to backup my changes.

Comment: Then set up a backup schedule that does a daily delta/incremental, rather than a full backup. Cobian Backup is an example of a tool that would let you do this. And OneDrive would only upload changed files. Sure you have the initial 15GB upload, but after that it should be much less.

Comment: @spikey_richie, why backup to OneDrive or another document store when you can use the built-in functionality of the source control system you're using?  Storing your working folders on one-drive is an even worse solution, it causes all kinds fo issues.

Answer (score 0):

Shelving is a simple way of storing your changed files. Your process is a bit convoluted. I'd simply run:

```
tf vc shelve /replace "daily backup" /noprompt /recursive
```

The command happens transactionally, so when it succeeds is replaced the old shelveset. If it fails, your previous changes will remain in tact.

An even better approach would be to craft smaller changes and to check in more often. That way your changes aren't just store on the server, but also integrated with your peers.

Visual Studio also has a built-in UI to suspend your changes. Open the <kbd>My Work</kbd> pael in Team Explorer and hit the <kbd>Suspend work</kbd> option. It will create a shelveset in the background.

[image: Suspend work]

The next day, simply <kbd>Resume</kbd> work:

[image: Resume work]

Comment: Wow ! That's a very good (and comprehensive) answer, thank you. I will test all the different approaches you detailed us in your post.

Comment: Anyway, crafting smaller changes may result in too many changesets to keep in mind to merge trough all the branches (integration, pre-production and production), so I think that approach would add extra-work and complexity in my environment.

Comment: If you just merge the branch as a whole (instead if cherry picking), it should not matter how many times you checked in. I highly discourage cherry picking anyway, except for hotfixing released branches...

Comment: can you please describe what do you mean by "merge the branch as a whole ?" I assume it means to include all my changesets at once in the first merge, so the next one will have only one changeset. It's like that ?

Comment: Yeah. when you rightclick a branch and pick "merge" from the context menu, the default is to merge all changes between the branches, but the end result is only a single changeset on the target branch,